# How to place text next to each other in TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am currently working on a little license plate generator and I'm trying to place some text, followed by an image and followed by some text again. However, I'm hardcoding all the positioning and it's not working when the data changes (e.g smaller text results in larger space)

My question is, how do I turn my solution into a more general solution. The main issue is that if I have a text with less characters, the text is not being auto aligned and spaced again. I'm not sure why my code is not working. Here's what I wrote:

```
$left_text_x = 85;
$left_text_y = 50;

$middle_img_top_x = $left_text_x + 15.8;
$middle_img_top_y = $y + 0.6;

$middle_img_bottom_x = $left_text_x + 15.3;
$middle_img_bottom_y = $y + 5.1;

$middle_text_x = $middle_img_bottom_x + 4.7;
$middle_text_y = $left_text_y;

$right_text_x = $middle_text_x + 11.3;
$right_text_y = $left_text_y;

//Text
$pdf->Text($left_text_x, $left_text_y, 'AAA', false, false, true, 0, 0, '', false, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M', false ); //Left
$pdf->Image('../../images/bundesland/Baden-Wurttemberg.png', $middle_img_top_x, $middle_img_top_y, 4, 4, '', '', '', false, 300); //Top img mid
$pdf->Image('../../images/plakette/rose.png', $middle_img_bottom_x, $middle_img_bottom_y, 5, 5, '', '', '', false, 300); //Bottom img mid

$pdf->Text($middle_text_x, $middle_text_y, 'AA', false, false, true, 0, 0, '', false, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M', false ); //Middle
$pdf->Text($right_text_x, $right_text_y, 'AAA', false, false, true, 0, 0, '', false, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M', false ); //Right
```

Here are my results:
[image]

Here's one that gives the unnecessary space:
[image]

Here's another one:
[image]

So as you can see, the space is not being adjusted automatically although my code looks fine. I know there is a logical error but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT: MORE DETAIL ON THE FOLLOWING LINK**
[TCPDF Text and Image Positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54893780/tcpdf-text-and-image-positioning)

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried it previously during my research but I couldn't get it working. Probably still logic error. I asked a more detailed question yesterday(you can check from my profile). I am not able to link it here for some reason. I edited my question above to include it. Can you please have a look at it? Thanks

Comment: What font are you using? This looks a lot like spacing issues normally associated with fonts that aren't fixed. My original suggestion was for the wrong package though I'm still pretty sure that the solution is going to require calculating the correct amount of space being consumed by the characters that were entered.

Comment: @Dave Yep, you're right. I figured it out. The space was the actual issue but by using the GetStringWidth, I managed to use that and calculating the next position for the placement. Epic stuff! Thanks

Comment: Ha, good. Guess I should have answered instead of commenting lolol

Comment: @Dave Haha, not too late, I would like to see you solution actually. Mine is not very clean but is doing the job for now.

Comment: Considering that I used fpdf it's going to look a bit different :) This produces a **To:** address with the elements of the address lined up on their left side. `    $ourpdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
    $to_offset = $ourpdf->GetStringWidth('To:') + 27;
    $ourpdf->Cell(0,4,'To:',0,0);
    $ourpdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $ourpdf->SetXY($to_offset,75);
    $ourpdf->Cell(0,4,$coop_data['name'],0,0);
    $ourpdf->SetXY($to_offset,79);
    $ourpdf->Cell(0,4,$coop_data['contact'],0,1);
    $ourpdf->SetXY($to_offset,83);
    $ourpdf->Cell(0,4,$coop_data['address1'],0,1);`

Comment: The important thing is the calculation of the offset after setting the font (which of course allows the width to be calculated correctly).